# knex: how to rename many existing tables in Directus 10?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, knex.js, directus

I installed Directus 10 over an existing (TYPO3) projet and want to rename tables now. To do so, the Directus docs recommend to create a migration, which I did. There is a helper file with a constant that holds an array of the old and the new table names like this:

```js
const { $renameTablesString } = [
     { origName: "tx_rwfm_domain_model_address_addresscategory_mm", 
       newName: "rwfm_mm_address_addresscategory;"},

     { origName: "tx_rwfm_domain_model_address_location_mm", 
       newName: "rwfm_mm_address_location;"},

     { origName: "tx_rwfm_domain_model_address_person_mm", 
       newName: "rwfm_mm_address_person;"},

     ...
]
```

This file is imported in the migration file and then lopped-over in the `up` function that Directus requires to use:

```js
import { $renameTablesString } from '../utils/rename-tables'

// Rename all tables
export async function up(knex) {
    $renameTablesString.forEach(async item => {
        await knex.schema
            .renameTable(item.orig, item.newitem)
            .dropTable(item.orig);
    })
};
```

Upon running `npx directus database migrate:up 2023-06-23__002__rename-tables.js` (from within a local Docker instance) I get this error message:

> Migration keys collide!
> Please ensure that every migration uses a unique key.

#### Questions

- Why does this happen?
- What do I have to adapt to make this migration work?